# Trouble with strcpy function

Tags: c++

I have a user defined class, one of whose members is a `char*` type. When I try to initialize it in the constructor I get an error saying `error C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead.`

However, when I changed strcpy to strcpy_s, it would still give the following error `IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "strcpy_s" matches the argument list argument types are: (char *, char *)`

Let's say `Student` is the class and `char* name;` is one of the data members.So, my constructor is like:

```
Student (char* s = NULL) {
    if (s != NULL) {
         name = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
         //strcpy(name,s);
         strcpy_s(name,s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because strcpy_s requires an additional parameter to specify how many bytes to copy.

See here:  http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/118771/

Comment: So, if the number of bytes in variable, how do I do it in this case?

Comment: Can I just enter an arbitrary max size, say 100 as the second argument?

Comment: I don't understand this. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: @Grendan `strcpy_s(name,s,strlen(s) + 1);`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I guess you got the arguments order wrong?

Comment: @Grendan May be. Replace with `strcpy_s(name,strlen(s) + 1,s);`, I'd guess you got your question wrong.

Comment: Woah, I'm just politely pointing out that the second argument looks like the number of bytes to copy . BTW you are a legend and I'm a rookie if that makes you happy.

Comment: It stills says strcpy_s was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @Grendan `strcpy_s()` isn't any standard. It's some M$ specific stuff IIRC.